# I cant print from my ArrayList filled with Order Objects

Tags: java, sql, jsp

So I get a nullpointer exception when trying to print from an arraylist, and I cant seem to understand why, since I'm still pretty new to coding. Keep in mind that I store the list as an attribute on my session, which gets created when u login. Here is example 1 where I create and try to add to the list:

```
public static ArrayList<Order> getOrdersByUserId( int userid ) throws LoginSampleException {
    try {
        Connection con = Connector.connection();
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM `order` "
                + "WHERE fk_userid=?";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement( SQL );
        ps.setInt( 1, userid );
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            Order order = new Order(rs.getInt("length"), rs.getInt("width"), rs.getInt("height"));
            orders.add(order);
        }
        return orders;
    } catch ( ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex ) {
        throw new LoginSampleException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is example 2 where I store the list in my session.

```
public class ViewOrders extends Command {

@Override
String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws LoginSampleException {
    ArrayList<Order> ol = new ArrayList();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if ( session.getAttribute("ordersByUserID") == null ) {
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute( "user" );
        ol = LogicFacade.getOrdersByUserID( user.getId() );
        System.out.println( "session not found" );
        request.getSession().setAttribute( "ordersByUserID", ol );
    } 
    return "vieworders";
}
```

}

And here is example 3 where I try to print from it and I get NullPointerException:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <td>This is your previous orders</td>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%
                    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("user") != null) { 
                        List<Order> orderlist = (List<Order>)request.getSession().getAttribute("ordersById");
                        for (int i = 0; i < orderlist.size(); i++) { %>
                            <a href="vieworderdetails.jsp?orderID=<%out.println(orderlist.get(i).getId());%>">
                                <%
                                    out.println(orderlist.get(i).getId());
                                %>
                            </a> <%
                        }
                    }
                %>       
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```